# iTunes accidentally deleted on iMac G5 with OS X 10.4.11 - how to install iTunes?

Tags: itunes, imac, powerpc, macos

I accidentally deleted iTunes on my old iMac G5 running Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.11. It is not in the trash, and I would really like to get it back. I tried getting the latest version of iTunes available for my system from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1056?locale=en_US. When I tried to open the DMG file it gave me, all I got was a notice that said "The following disk images failed to mount: iTunes9.2.1.dmg".

Got any suggestions? I would really like to have iTunes back.

Comment: Image mounted fine for me; have you tried mounting it on another computer and moving the installer over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your downloaded DMG *should* work, but assuming you still have the Mac OS X Tiger install DVD you could try the following instead:

- Insert the Mac OS X Tiger install DVD
- When Finder opens the Mac OS X Install DVD window, scroll down till you see the *System* folder
- Navigate to System > Installation > Packages
- Locate the **iTunes.pkg** and double-click on it
- This *should* launch the iTunes installer
- Follow the steps to see if you can install iTunes.

Assuming you can, after doing so use the **Apple > Software Update** option to update it or launch iTunes and go to **iTunes > Check for Updates** option instead.