# How do I restore an accidentally deleted Siri.app?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, siri

I accidentally deleted Siri.app from my applications folder in macOS High Sierra. I don't want to do a reinstall cause I have removed various system, files which I don't need one by one by looking up the processes via activity monitor now reinstall macOS High Sierra would reinstall all those system and missing default Applications, so how can I skip this traditional way of restoring system files via Install macOS High Sierra.app and only install Siri.app via an external source?

I have already checked this answer [iTunes accidentally deleted on iMac G5 with OS X 10.4.11 - how to install iTunes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280771/itunes-accidentally-deleted-on-imac-g5-with-os-x-10-4-11-how-to-install-itunes) and I guess this is for Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.11 so I didn't took the pain to download the Install macOS High Sierra.app and check it for myself!

Comment: Only advice: Reinstall High Sierra! And - urgent measure - enable SIP afterwards! We don't know which system files/frameworks/drivers are already deleted! Siri may rely on them and simply restoring the bundle (like in [Accidentally deleted a system framework, macOS screwed!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300222/accidentally-deleted-a-system-framework-macos-screwed) may not work.

Comment: It is the 5th time I am fully formatting my Mac and reinstalling macOS

Comment: What's your goal deleting arbitrary apps/frameworks/system files?

Comment: See I have a 1.4 Ghz iMac so running simple codes sometimes become a headache so I was searching for a way to get over this hurdle when I saw that a lot of processes are sucking up huge chunks of memory (useless ones - which I don't know of-course) so I deleted some of those processes and surprisingly the system became faster and more responsive!

Comment: Please use guides like [5 Tips to Optimize Mac Performance](https://nektony.com/uncategorized/5-tips-to-optimize-mac-performance) or [How to Speed Up Slow macOS Sierra](https://macpaw.com/how-to/speed-up-macos-sierra) to enhance speed. And compare the time required to download and install High Sierra five times with the "saved" time.

Comment: @klanomath Ok I am restoring my SSD question, Ok now that I will install macOS on an external SSD how can I use the old internal Hard Drive as the downloads drive, I mean like windows has drive e drive d one for the OS and the other for the downloads I know these are just partitions, so how can I have a setup like this with two drives?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can simply download the High Sierra installer to your HDD, then partition and format the SSD, then - in the installer - choose the SSD as destination (instead of the HDD to which the installer defaults to), then wait 25 minutes and your Mac will boot to the new system on the SSD. In one config step (after booting to the SSD) you will be asked to migrate data from an old install: choose the system on your HDD then. Done!

Comment: @klanomath Ok let me be a little more elaborate, see now that the mac is running on the new SSD so whatever I do, whatever I download all the informations will be stored in the SSD (My Assumption), so my question is how can I use the old HDD as the Storage to store all these informations and use the SSD only as the boot Disk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66376/discussion-between-klanomath-and-sayan).